# flutter: provider dosen't work in statefulwidget

Tags: flutter

I create a new flutter demo and modify it to use the provider package. But it doesn't work. And here is my code.

```
class MyState {
  MyState();
  int cnt = 0;
  void increase() {
    print("increase. $cnt");
    cnt++;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Provider<MyState>(
        create: (_) => MyState(),
        child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Consumer<MyState>(
              builder: (context, state, _) {
                return Text(
                  "${state.cnt}",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: Provider.of<MyState>(context, listen: false).increase,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When press the button, the UI is not rebuilt. And as the printed messages show, the cnt field of Mystate had been changed. Why? May provider can not be used in statefulwidget?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Provider**: You can use Provider to provide a value anywhere in the widget tree. It will not rebuild the widget tree whenever the value changes. It simply passes the model to its descendant's widget in the widget tree.

**ChangeNotifierProvider**: ChangeNotifierProvider listens for changes in the model object. It rebuilds the dependents widgets whenever **ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners** is called.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyState with ChangeNotifier {
  MyState();

  int cnt = 0;

  void increase() {
    print("increase. $cnt");
    cnt++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyState>(
      create: (context) => MyState(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page Title"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Consumer<MyState>(
                builder: (context, counter, child) => Text(
                  '${counter.cnt}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: Provider.of<MyState>(context, listen: false).increase,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I come from vue and in vue data and model are just bound. So I think provider is just some thing like this, but it is not. Thanks.

Comment: how is this the accepted answer? The answer not even read the question. Question is: You have a Change Provider and ALSO a StatefulWidget, then, how do you combine the stateful widget state with the global app state?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: `MyState` extends `ChangeNotifier` and use `notifyListeners()` 
Step 2: Use `ChangeNotifierProvider` 
code snippet

```
class MyState extends ChangeNotifier {
  MyState();
  int cnt = 0;
  void increase() {
    print("increase. $cnt");
    cnt++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => MyState(),
        child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyState extends ChangeNotifier {
  MyState();
  int cnt = 0;
  void increase() {
    print("increase. $cnt");
    cnt++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => MyState(),
        child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Consumer<MyState>(
              builder: (context, state, _) {
                return Text(
                  "${state.cnt}",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: Provider.of<MyState>(context, listen: false).increase,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and Shubham Narkhede's answer give the reason, so I accept that. Thank you very much.